# String contains non-overlapping letter pairs

Tags: strings, elixir

I was trying my hand at learning Elixir via ancient adventofcode puzzles and was trying to write a function to satisfy this requirement:

> It contains a pair of any two letters that appears at least twice in
>   the string without overlapping, like xyxy (xy) or aabcdefgaa (aa), but
>   not like aaa (aa, but it overlaps).

Here is what I came up with, but it feels like it might be unwieldy. Is there a way to make it more elegant?

```
  def has_non_overlapping_pair(string) do
    0..String.length(string)-2 
      |> Enum.map(fn n ->
          String.slice(string, n, 2)
      end)
      |> Enum.reduce(["_"], fn pair, acc ->
          if pair == hd(acc) do ["_"|acc] 
          else [pair|acc] end
      end)
      |> count_occurrences
      |> Map.delete("_")
      |> Map.values
      |> Enum.any?(fn val -> val > 1 end)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a map to store the pairs with their first occurrence while iterating over the pairs. Break if the current pair was already found at a position less than the current position minus 1.

```
def has_non_overlapping_pair(string) do
  0..String.length(string) - 2
  |> Enum.reduce_while(%{}, fn n, m ->
    pair = String.slice(string, n, 2)
    pos  = Map.get(m, pair, n)
    cond do
      pos == n     -> {:cont, Map.put(m, pair, n)}
      pos == n - 1 -> {:cont, m}
      true         -> {:halt, true}
    end
  end) == true
end
```